# Analytic representatives for Kahler classes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If we are given  compact complex manifold $X$ and a Kahler class $[\omega]$, 
can we always find a positive definite representative $\omega \in [\omega]$ that is 
real analytic?

Comment: For hyperkahler manifold, S.Boucksom showed that a $(1, 1)$ class $ \{\omega\} $ is Kahler if and only if it lies in the positive part of the Beauville-Bogomolov quadratic cone and moreover $\int_C \omega > 0$
for all rational curves $C ⊂ X$. For general case it is a conjecture yet! SEE : Cones positifs des varietes complexes compactes, Thesis, Grenoble 2002.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Run the Kähler-Ricci heat flow 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\omega(t)\right) = -\mathrm{Ric}\bigl(\omega(t)\bigr)
$$ 
with initial condition $\omega(0) = \omega$. This will exist for some time interval $[0,T)$, and the $\omega_t$ for $t>0$ will all be be real-analytic with respect to the natural real-analytic structure on $M$ given by the complex structure.  Note that we have
$$
\left[\omega(t)\right] = \left[\omega(0)\right] - t\,c_1(M).
$$

Now, for $0<t_1<t_2<T$, with $t_1$ very small with respect to $t_2$, consider the $2$-form
$$
\omega(t_1,t_2) = \frac{\omega(t_1) - (t_1/t_2)\ \omega(t_2)}{1-t_1/t_2}
$$
It is easy to see that, if $t_1/t_2>0$ is very small, then $\omega(t_1,t_2)$ is a positive $(1,1)$-form.  It is real-analytic and, by construction, it satisfies
$$
\left[\omega(t_1,t_2)\right] = \left[\omega(0)\right] = [\omega].
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By Kahler Ricci flow you mean $$\partial_{t}\omega_{t}=-Ric(\omega_{t})$$? Sorry but i don't see why $\omega_{0}$ and $\omega_{t}$ are cohomologous.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have remembered that you have to do a linear combination in general.  I'll fix that.  Thanks for pointing out that oversight.

Comment: Many thanks! can you tell me a reference where it is proved that the evolution of a smooth Kahler metric through Kahler Ricci flow is real analytic?

Comment: It's in the literature, but I don't remember an explicit reference.  It follows immediately, though, from Bando's original 1987 result that any solution of Ricci-flow on a compact Riemannian manifold is, at any positive time, real-analytic in geodesic normal coordinates coupled with the fact that, in the Kähler-Ricci case, the complex structure $J$ is parallel with respect to each metric $g(t)$ associated to $\omega(t)$ for $t>0$.  This implies that $J$ is real-analytic in geodesic normal coordinates for each $g(t)$ and hence $J$-holomorphic functions are real-analytic in such coordinates.

Comment: @RobertBryant No, your answer need to be revised! You may never have such initial metric when $0<kod(X)<\dim X$. See https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01413754

Comment: @HassanJolany:  I don't understand your objection.  By hypothesis, the class $[\omega]$ has a Kähler representative (i.e., a positive closed $(1,1)$-form), namely $\omega$ itself; that's what it means for it to be a Kähler class, rather than just a $(1,1)$-class.